# Why does my related data not update and give me a null reference error in my ASP.NET Core Application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two tables of related data with navigation properties.  When I try to update the data the parent data updates but the related data doesn't and I have a null reference exception error as well.  I need help understanding why and what I can do to correct it and if my setup is correct.  I've read the documentation but annoyingly, it's directed towards updating a dropdown list which isn't much help to me.

Here are my entity classes:

**Car.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class Car : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public int Reg { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Hire> Hires { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Hire.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class Hire
    {
        public int HireId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So, as you can see above, with navigation properties, one 'Car' can have many 'Hires'.  No on to the view, here is how I display that information in my edit view, I'm not sure about enumerating over the cars, it doesn't feel like it's quite right.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Data.Car>
<form id="carEditForm" asp-controller="Car" asp-action="Edit" method="post" asp-antiforgery="true">
    @foreach (var car in Model)
    {           
        <!-- /Car Data --> 
        <input type="text" asp-for="@car.Make" name="Make" />
        <input type="text" asp-for="@car.Model" name="Model" />

        <!-- /Hire Data -->
        @foreach (var hire in item.Hires)
        {
             <input type="text" asp-for="@hire.HireDate" name="HireDate" />
        }
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
</form>
```

Here is my edit code for updating all the date in both tables.

```
  [HttpPost]
  [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
  public IActionResult Edit(Car car)
        {
            var data = _context.Car
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(t => t.Hires)
                .FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id.Equals(car.Id));

            _context.Car.Update(car);            

            foreach (var hire in data.Hires)
            {
                _context.Hire.Update(hire);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return View();
        }

public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var data = _context.Car.Include(d => d.Hires).Where(v => v.Id == id);
    return View(data);
}
```

When I try to update my data I get the following null reference exception error, I have a feeling it's linked to the fact the car is enumerated over, I'm not sure:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.  @foreach (var car in Model)

The 'Car' table is updated but the 'Hire' isn't.  I think my setup is just not quite right and would like to have some help to fix it.

Comment: Instead of using `foreach` you can use `_context.Hire.UpdateRange(data.Hires)`.

Comment: can I see what you're passing to the view?! Add your `Get` Method Code to the question.

Comment: Are you using EF? could you please post the code that saves the data to the database?

Comment: @YanivAmrami I am using EF, yes, the code that saves the data to the database is in my question already unless I'm misunderstanding you.  The code declares the database context directly and then, using ASp.NET Core you can simply call 'save' or 'update'.

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi I have now added that code to my question.

Comment: In your view, you expect to have an `IEnumerable<MyProject.Data.Car>` but you are passing something else `_context.Vessel`. are you fetching correct data ?!
review it and let me know what happen.

Comment: can you post the Car.Update() and Hire.Update() methods?

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi That was a typo, corrected to Car and Hires.

Comment: This mentioned error occurred because the model that you passed has not any `Car`! so when it wants to iterate on it, it show this error. are you sure `data` is populated by some `Cars` in the `Edit` method? Debug it.

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi Yes, a breakpoint shows the data when the edit moethod is hit when you load the page.  So there is data there and the input fields are populated as you'd expect.  When you submit any changes however, problems occur.

Answer (score 1):

I think u need to pass collection to view as Model in method where is "carEditForm"
Maybe such:

```
return View(cars);
```